# Como organizar a saída que o Python retorna no módulo Pymongo?

Tags: python, pymongo

Estou tentando retornar database e mais funções. Ex:

```
mongodb = MongoClient(args.ip, int(porta))
database = mongodb.list_database_names()
print (database)
```

Mas quando retorna a resposta, vem assim

```
['admin', 'config', 'local']
```

Como posso organizar a resposta? Ex:

```
    admin
    config
    local
```

etc...

sem colchete, aspas e virgulas...? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você você recebe é uma lista de nomes de databases, então é normal que a representação do objeto venha com colchetes e vírgulas.

Se você deseja ter uma saída diferente, você pode percorrer todos os nomes da lista utilizando um bloco `for` e imprimir cada nome. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
mongodb = MongoClient(args.ip, int(porta))
databases = mongodb.list_database_names()

print("Databases:\n")

for name in databases:
    print("-", name)
```